# How to check in golang if a particular directory has a mount --bind on it?

Tags: go, exec, bind, mount

I use following command to check if a directory is mounted.

```
res := exec.Command("mount", "|", "grep", toDir, ">", "/dev/null").Run()
```

But it returns `exit status 1` no matter if a directory is mounted or not.

mount | grep /path/to/dir > /dev/null

On command line works fine.

How can I get the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your command involves pipes, you can pass it as a command string to bash instead of executing it directly. Something like this should work.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    res, _ := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "mount | grep /home").Output()
    fmt.Printf("%s", res)
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `sh -c` and using the command directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use language machinery for piping, something like

```
c1 := exec.Command("mount")
c2 := exec.Command("grep", toDir)
c2.Stdin, _ = c1.StdoutPipe()
c2.Stdout = os.DevNull
c2.Start()
c1.Run()
c2.Wait()
```